# How to convert date time format to date and time object?

Tags: c#, datetime

What is the best way to convert to date and time the string:

`"Jan  7 09:27:56"` can be also like this: `"Jan  12 09:27:56"`

Comment: DateTime.Parse("Jan 7 09:27:56");

Comment: @Barak Run-time exception: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `MMM  d HH:mm:ss` as a [custom date and time format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with a *english-based* and uses `:` as a [`TimeSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator)  culture like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture).

```
var s = "Jan 7 09:27:56";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or

```
var s = "Jan 12 09:27:56";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I did not downvote. But I can tell you there's no form of that method with 3 args.

Comment: @nikhilvartak Ops, sorry. It should be `ParseExact` not `TryParseExact` :) Fixed.

Comment: I did not downvote. But I can tell you there's no way those original dates will be validated with the missing space in your format string.

Comment: @Gustav Fixed that part as well. As an alternative, `DateTimeStyles.AllowInnerWhite` can be used so there is no worry about extra white spaces inside of the format.

Comment: Then I would rephrase: There _is_ a way. Thanks, I haven't paid attention to that third optional and quite useful parameter.